# build error when add Admob in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, admob

I tried lots of source code and many questions here but no solution is working for me.
When I tried to add admob to my existing project I got the following  error in Xcode, please see the screenshot :

[image: error build]

I have all frameworks such as store kit and others. See the second screenshot :

[image]

I have added iAd network without any problems, but I'm unable to add admob. Please help

In case the image is not clear please see the error text here :

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/hussainbarakat/Desktop/ARSSReader21-1-2013
>   copy1/../../Documents/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.3.0/Add-ons/GoogleAnalyticsiOS_2.0beta4/Library'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/hussainbarakat/Desktop/ARSSReader21-1-2013
>   copy1/../../Documents/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.3.0' ld: warning:
>   ignoring file /Users/hussainbarakat/Desktop/ARSSReader21-1-2013
>   copy1/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit, missing required architecture i386
>   in file /Users/hussainbarakat/Desktop/ARSSReader21-1-2013
>   copy1/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit (2 slices) Undefined symbols for
>   architecture i386:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)   "_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
>         -[GADOpener openInAppStore:fallbackURLString:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Have you added updated admobe sdk and libAdapterIAd.a for armv7s?

Comment: The error here is that the framework you're trying to link is not a FAT framework for i386, and it's ARM only

Comment: Sadia : how can I add this is there any good tutorial showing that .

Comment: Richard J. Ross : thanks but I don't what's the wrong ? what I need to do now .

Comment: I found that the error is happen when I add the code in ViewDidload in my file.m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution !! The problem is with Storekit Framework, I had dragged this frame from into my project from previous time, so when I deleted this framework, & then add it again from build setting > Build phases , then add the StoreKit frame work, the error is gone.

Comment: This is solved my issue . also added -ObjC in the other links flags .then it's works fine.

Answer (score 0):

follow this [tutorial](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/09/migrating-to-admob-v62-for-ios.html)

And make ADSupport.framework optional

download libAdapterId,a form here https://dl.google.com/dl/googleadmobadssdk/libadapteriad.zip
Do net set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property. It is supported for iOS6 and later

Comment: Thanks Sadia, but my deployment target is for iOS 5.0 .