# error on AdMob integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, admob

I Have added Addmob sdk in my project and even added all framework needed. But m getting below error for StoreKit framework even i have added it in my project but still getting error..

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-    L/Users/company/Downloads/projectname/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.4.2/Add-    ons/GoogleAnalyticsiOS_2.0beta4/Library'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/company/Downloads/projectname/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.4.2'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/company/Downloads/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/company/Downloads/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
"_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
  -[GADOpener openInAppStore:fallbackURLString:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I search a lot but in every post its sid to add Storkit.. but i have already added it but still getting error. even i have cleaned the project a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure that you have added the following libraries,

```
1.AudioToolbox
2.MessageUI
3.SystemConfiguration
4.CoreGraphics
```

Also the frameworks,

```
1.MessageUI.framework
2.StoreKit.framework
3.SystemConfiguration.framework
```

According to your error message there is a problem with `StoreKit.framework`...Please verify that...

Refer: [build error when add Admob in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642180/build-error-when-add-admob-in-ios-app)

Comment: already done all these? is there any framework version issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add `AdSupport.framework`, also make it as optional

Answer (score 0):

It says that your StoreKit binary is not build for i386. This should not happen with the default one. Did you download if separately from somewhere? You can find the default here:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer‌​/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework`

Use that.