# Admob ads causing error on iOS app

Tags: ios, admob

I am trying to integrate Admob ads into an iOS app and they were working perfectly yesterday. The project is unchanged and I run the project today and I get this:

[image]

Why is this happening? I did not move the project or anything, it looks like it is failing to locate something??

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15652498/334091

Comment: well I deleted all the admob files and added them again and the error went away, the warnings remain... I'll play around with it and see what happens

Comment: The error returns every time I quit Xcode, to remove the error I just delete the admob files and add them again...

Comment: Do you copy the libraries to your project or you just linked them?

Comment: yes, originally I thought maybe I had forgotten to, but that is not the issue